# global variable

Tags: r

I have one question about using global variable in R.  I write two examples

First version:

```
a <- 1
fun <- function(b){
    return(a+b)
}
fun(b)
```

Second version:

```
a <- 1 
fun <- function(a,b){
    return(a+b)
}
fun(a,b)
```

I want to know which version is correct or recommand.

Comment: What do you mean which version is correct? They both work. Define "correct".

Comment: In the second version, you cannot call `fun` without providing `a`. So the function does not use the global `a` but it's first argument to calculate `a + b`. The fact that you call it using the global `a` is another matter. In general, try to avoid global variables and always pass variables in function arguments like your second version does. It's not a matter of 'correctness' but rather good practice, which helps avoid bugs, makes your code more readable and easier to change, etc. Hadley's book has a good section on functions and scoping http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

Comment: ok, got it. THX!

Answer (score 2):

Relying on global state inside functions is frowned upon for various reasons (which can be roughly grouped under the caption [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29). So the second version would be superior in most scenarios.

However, the situation changes once the variable is defined inside a non-global environment. In that case, you’ve encapsulated your state into something that’s put away neatly. This is sometimes useful, because it allows you to create functions based on some input.

The classical example is something like this:

```
adder = function (value_to_add) {
    function (x) {
        x + value_to_add
    }
}
```

This may look obscure but it’s simply a function that returns another function: you can use it to *create* functions. Here, for example, we create a function that takes one argument and adds the value 5 to it:

```
add5 = adder(5)
```

And here’s one that adds π to its argument:

```
add_pi = adder(pi)
```

Both of these are normal functions:

```
> add5(10)
[1] 15
> add_pi(10)
[1] 13.14159
```

Both of these functions, `add5` and `add_pi`, access a variable, `value_to_add`, that’s outside of the function itself, in a separate environment. And it’s important to realise that these are *different* environments from each other: `add5`’s `value_to_add` is a different value, in a different environment, from `add_pi`’s `value_to_add`:

```
> environment(add5)$value_to_add
[1] 5
> environment(add_pi)$value_to_add
[1] 3.141593
```

(`environment(f)` allows you to inspect the environment to which a function `f` belongs. `$` is used to access names inside that environment.)